# Gatsby title metadata is not showing

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

`Gatsby.js` is not showing title metadata, instead its showing the `site_url`.

am using https://github.com/jaxx2104/gatsby-starter-bootstrap

Example: `http:localhost:8000` on home page

and `http:localhost:8000/about` on about page

I want it to just show the title of the website.

gatsby-config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Indo Maroc Engineering Limited',
    description: 'Construction Company',
    author: 'VishnuDileesh',
    twitter: '',
    adsense: '',
  },
```

Layout index.js look like this

```
<div>
   <Navi title={siteMetadata.title} {...this.props} />
     {children}
   <Footer title={siteMetadata.title} author={siteMetadata.author} />
</div>
```

Comment: You know that we cannot view localhost examples?  Could you post the code you use?

Comment: A step forward, but where is React helmet?

Comment: react helmet is added as the plugin in gatsby.config file. if we inspect the live site and look at the title tag, its empty, <title data-react-helmet="true"></title>

Comment: Thanks, resolved it, all i had to do was make the change in <Helmet title="mytilte"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use 'react-helmet' to manage metadata from react.

Comment: am using react-helmet metadata and the variables are set correct but, still gatsby is pulling the siteurl as the title and not the content from title variabel